# ServiceM8 API disabled?

Tags: get

`myClientID` & `myURL` are just placeholders for real values.

It seems that API access is inconsistent.
I was working on this last night, and it was working fine.
I would do a GET to the URL below:

https://www.servicem8.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=myclientID&scope=read_jobs&redirect_uri=http://myURL

This would pop-up an authorization screen where I would enter username & password
Then a pop-up would appear that with an “`ALLOW`” button
Once I clicked `ALLOW` it would forward to our website `http://myURL`
It also appended `code=random-generated-temp-code&state=` to the end of the URL
I then executed a **POST** command to generate the `access_token` from the `temp-code`

Today the form that asks the user to `ALLOW` does not pop-up, and so it does not generate the `temp-api-code`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In order to help, you'll need to provide some description of what results you do get. OAuth isn't responsible for generating popups. What happens when you visit the URL with your real client id and redirect URL?